# prove an analytic function has at least n zeros

Tags: complex-analysis

I`m confused about this problem: 
Let G be a bounded region in C whose boundary consists of n circles.
Suppose that f is a non-constant function analytic on G: Show that
if absolute value of f(z) = 1 for all z in the boundary of G then f has at least n zeros (counting multiplicities) in G.

What does it mean that boundary consists of n circles? How can I start solving the problem? 
Any help please...

Comment: The description of the boundary just means that $G$ is in $n$ pieces, and each one has a circle for its boundary. For instance the unit disk is a region with $1$ circle for its boundary; the union of the disks of radius $1/3$ centered at $i,2i,...,ni$ has for its boundary the $n$ circles of the same radius and the same centers.

Comment: *Region* usually means that your set is connected, so $G$ consists of a disk with $n-1$ circular holes. An annulus would be an example with $n=2$.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/51029/zeros-of-a-holomorphic-function

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what tools you have at your disposal, but this follows from some basic topology. The assumptions imply that $f$ is a [proper map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map) from the region $G$ to the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$. As such the map has a topological degree, and since the preimage of the boundary $|z|=1$ contains $n$ components, this degree has to be at least $n$, meaning that every $z\in\mathbb{D}$ has to have at least $n$ preimages, counted with multiplicity.

Comment: I definitely don`t know about that in topology, I meant to do that in complex analysis, but I`ll try to use what you said and see if that will help me.